# variables in webpack's css loader

Tags: css, webpack

I started using the webpack's css loader and I find it really useful in terms of having "local scope" in css. What I need is `variables` e.g. I have something like this

```
:local(#names > input){
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #FF5251;
}
```

I want to define a variable for the color, e.g. `$pink = '#FF5251`
**Is there a way to do that inside this css file with the css loader or the only solution is to change loader and use `sass` ?**

I mean, since it is not a "real" css file and it already has things like `local` and `composes`, someone would expect support for variables.

I didn't find any example on the [repo's readme](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader)

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy unfortunately no, I will make an issue on github to ask about.